# Is there a .net IoC that can inject properties before invoking an objects constructor?

Tags: .net, inversion-of-control

Is anyone aware of an IoC container that injects properties prior to the constructor being invoked?

I'm working on in-house framework where I don't want to force people to derive from a constructor with multiple params to use my base classes (it's tedious stuff like schedulers etc and if I add more to the base then it will be a huge job to update everyones code who is using the base). It would be preferable if they were set before the users constructor was invoked so that I don't have to have a separate OnInitialised virtual method where they could finish initialisation that is dependent on those properties.

*edit*

To clarify, what I'm wanting here is for property injection to be equivalent to field initialisers in the construction chain.

1. Derived static fields
2. Derived static constructor
3. Derived instance fields
4. Base static fields
5. Base static constructor
6. Base instance fields
7. Base instance constructor
8. Derived instance constructor

i.e. at around 6.5 or maybe 7.5 (although that would be a little strange)

Comment: It's unclear what you even mean... how can you set properties before you've created an object?

Comment: I was thinking that by creating the object with GetUninitializedObject (), then injecting the properties and then invoking the constructor. Similar to placement new type stuff in C++.

Comment: I really, really hope that can't be done. It goes against everything in normal .NET coding. How are you going to test that code anyway?

Comment: I'm not sure I agree, it solves the problem of constructor dependency injection polluting the whole class hierarchy when creating a common base class. Say I have a base class for ViewModels used by 30+ developers and I need to inject a background/syncontext scheduler tuple, its unpleasant to do it through constructor injection. If I do it with property injection then they can't do any init that requires access to those schedulers until later, i.e. forcing me to create an OnInitialised virtual method on the base. So much for 'instantiation is initialisation' - and more complexity to the user.

Comment: I will conceed its not particularly idiomatic, so maybe thats reason enough to leave it alone. It does however address an issue with IoC and construction semantics.

Comment: As to testing the code, I could have a test that inspects the properties in the instantiated classes constructor?

Comment: Thinking about it, I can achieve the result I want in a roundabout way by having a static initialisation function that returns the init value for the variable. This could then use a service locator to get the container so the properties are resolved before the constructor runs. Would need to use tls here I think to avoid service location as need to control what container is used as this all needs to work within a scope.

Comment: Actually revising my opinion that it's not idiomatic. Generally when deriving from a base you expect its members to be initialised. Its seems to me that ioc is getting in the way of that idiomatic behaviour.

Comment: I don't see how. Take IoC out of the equation: how would you make sure everything's initialized by the time the constructor's finished *without* passing the dependencies into the constructor?

Comment: I'm talking about a base and derived class scenario here. e.g. ViewModelBase with MyViewModel : ViewModelBase. In the constructor of MyViewModel its preferable if the base classes fields are initialised so I can use them in the derived classes constructor. With IoC out of the equation this is normally the case. One way around this with IoC is to use the static field initialisation methods as per my solution below, but its pretty clunky. Essentially what I was asking for was for DependencyProperties to be treated as field initialisers in the construction chain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comments against question, this is the pattern that seems to address my need, but I will need to use TLS to avoid the service locator which is in this example (I need to control scope for the properties being set in this way).

```
public class TestBase
{
    private SchedulerContext schedulerContext = InitScheduler();
    public SchedulerContext SchedulerContext
    {
        get { return this.schedulerContext; }
    }

    private static SchedulerContext InitScheduler()
    {
        return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<SchedulerContext>();
    }

    public TestBase()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Is Instantiated: {0}", this.SchedulerContext != null);           
    }
}

public class TestDerived : TestBase
{
    public TestDerived()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Is Instantiated: {0}", this.SchedulerContext != null);
    }
}
```

This does at least avoid the horror of decomposing the languages object construction framework :)